# How do you simply hide an element without it collapsing in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table of todos and on the leftmost column are normally checkboxes to mark completed. I want to hide those checkboxes untill a user hovers over a task, upon which that tasks checkbox becomes visible.

Currently when I hide the checkboxes using

```
$('table#incompleted_tasks tr td input[type="checkbox"]').css('display', 'none');
```

the actual column collapses and following columns are shunted left. This means when i hover over a task the checkbox is expanded but everything is shunted right and thus misaligned.

Id like to preserver that hidden columns width but how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
$('table#incompleted_tasks tr td input[type="checkbox"]').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

The element will not be shown, but the place for it will be “held occupied” for in the page flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can set "visibility" to "hidden":

```
$('table#incompleted_tasks tr td input[type="checkbox"]').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```